# `outputFileNameMapping` uses the name of the artifact running the plugin instead of the dependency

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using `maven-assembly-plugin` v.3.3.0 with the following configuration in my assembly file (the module name is `example`):

pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
        <version>see-jgitver</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myLib</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myLib</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
```

Assembly file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includes>
                <include>*:tar.gz</include>
            </includes>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.groupId}${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

(Not sure if the `${artifact.groupId}` property is correct.)

The include tag matches artifact `A` and `B`.
I was expecting them to appear in the final package as
`A.tar.gz` and `B.tar.gz`.
Instead I get a single artifact called `example.tar.gz`

So, `artifact.artifactId` is referring to the example artifact, that is running the plugin, and not to the dependency. Is this expected behavior? How can I achieve my goal?

Additional info(edit):

- why do you like to use outputFileNameMapping?
  I'm trying to understand how it is used. In this case I have multiple dependencies with the same artifactId (although different groupId), so it would be useful to add the groupId to all of them.
- What is the problem?
  Although, there's a context here, which I tried to clarify with this edit, I think my question is really straightforward. From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) I was expecting a different behavior.
- Why have you changed the outputDirectory?
  I removed that tag, as it is not relevant in this case.
- Why an include on tar.gz?
  So, there are several dependencies that are being joined in single tar. This is not my project, is part of a bigger construction.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full pom file..furthermore why do you like to use outputFileNameMapping? What is the problem? Why have you changed the outputDirectory? Why an include on tar.gz?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. Thanks for your questions!